# What is the significance of the metallic device at the end of Glitch?

Tags: glitch

In the series finale of *Glitch* a small metallic device is given a lot of screen time.  Was this device featured or mentioned in earlier seasons?  I can't remember it being discussed in any earlier episodes.

Edit:  The image is shown below, it is from the final episode.

[image]

Comment: I have never seen the show or even heard of it, but that object is a *bosun's pipe* or *bosun's whistle*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boatswain%27s_call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object was shown repeatedly throughout the series to be in John's possession. Off the top of my head, I remember, for instance, the following instances:

- When he escapes from the Noregard lab, John makes sure to take the object with him.
- At the end of season 2, once the others have left the graveyard, he unpacks the object and whistles once, as if to try what will happen.

It was described as somehow bridging the boundary between life and death.

Answer (score 2):

The whistle is known as a Boatswain's whistle or pipe. It is used to communicate commands to the crew of a ship. As we know, William Blackburn was the captain of a ship in the 1700's when he first died by drowning. He knew he had to continue to protect the natural order of the universe and thereby save all life by sacrificing himself, and calling the risen to follow the order. Very interesting series!

Answer (score 0):

I think the sliver whistle was a way to control the ones resurrected, like when John blew the whistle the first time all of the risiners  stood still and was under control..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer needs more details.  What was the episode where the whistle seemed to control the risen?

Comment: Season 1ep6 around 22 minutes in, after Vic broke his leg he tried to persuade John to help him kill the risen, that's when John blew the whistle and all of the risen kind of froze in place and where hypnotised